# FileIO.WriteAsync hanging

Tags: c#, windows, io, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to work on a basic Windows 8 Store app, simply creating a new file and writing some sample data to it. However when I run the function I've written the app hangs and becomes unresponsive. I've tried two separate methods of file creation, and they both have the same effect:

Using the roaming folder:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder roamingFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
StorageFile file = await roamingFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
string[] data = { "New project", "000000000" , "" };
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, data[0]);
return new Project(file.Path, "New project", "", Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
```

With a file picker:

```
Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker fsp = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
        fsp.FileTypeChoices.Clear();
        fsp.FileTypeChoices.Add("Plain Text", new List<string>() { ".jwp" });
        fsp.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        fsp.SuggestedFileName = "New Project";
        StorageFile file = await fsp.PickSaveFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            string[] data = { "New project", "000000000" , "" };
            CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file);
            await FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(file, data);
            Windows.Storage.Provider.FileUpdateStatus status = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file);
            if (status == Windows.Storage.Provider.FileUpdateStatus.Complete)
            {
                return new Project(file.Path, "New project", "", Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Each time, the line it appears to hang on is:

```
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file,data[0]);
```

or:

```
await FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(file,data);
```

respectively.

Anybody have any idea what's going on here? There's certainly space on the drive I chose in the picker, and I'm even able to see that the picker method is definitely creating a file (albeit one of 0 bytes in size), but I can't really do anything with it.

Comment: The first method works fine for me.  Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Delete code until it starts to work to see which code is necessary to trigger the bug. Or create a brand new project, add the suspect line into it and run it. Does it still hang? Probably not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that somewhere up your call hierarchy, you're synchronously blocking on an asynchronous method (e.g., `Task.Wait` or `Task.Result`).

This prevents your method continuation from sync'ing back to the UI thread, causing a deadlock. [I explain this deadlock scenario in full detail on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

There are two guidelines to follow that will fix this:

1. Use `async` all the way down. Don't block on `async` code. Replace `Task.Wait`/`Task.Result` with `await` and allow it to grow.
2. Configure your context. If your `async` method doesn't need to access UI elements (or databound properties) after an `await`, then use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.