# NamedPipeClientStream WriteAsync deadlock

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I'm having some issues getting a bi-directional named pipe client working using `Tasks`.

First up, I know my server is working correctly as a previous iteration of this client code, which was synchronous, was able to send multiple messages in a row.

The first time I write a message using `WriteAsync` the message arrives the server however when I attempt to send a second message, my code enters `WriteAsync` and never leaves.

In looking for a solution I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/13335629/635129 which sounds similar however they mention using async all the way down and to not block async code which I think I'm doing (unless `Task.WaitAll(outboundTask, inboundTask)` inside an async function counts)

```
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
private Task pipeTask;

public void Start()
{
    pipeTask = RunPipeClient();
}

public void Stop()
{
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    pipeTask.Wait();
}

private async Task RunPipeClient()
{
    while (!cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        using (NamedPipeClientStream namedPipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream("NamedPipe"))
        {
            await namedPipeClient.ConnectAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            var outboundTask = ProcessOutbound(namedPipeClient);
            var inboundTask = ProcessInbound(namedPipeClient);

            Task.WaitAll(outboundTask, inboundTask);
        }
    }
}

private async Task ProcessOutbound(NamedPipeClientStream client)
{
    while (!outbox.IsCompleted && !cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var message = outbox.Take(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        byte[] msgBuff = message.ToByteArray();
        // The following line locks up
        await client.WriteAsync(msgBuff, 0, msgBuff.Length, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
}

private async Task ProcessInbound(NamedPipeClientStream client)
{
    // .....
    int bytesRead = await client.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    // .....
}
```

Does anything stand out as obviously wrong in the above code?
Is there anything wrong with creating two Tasks inside a task then using Tasks.WaitAll to wait for those two tasks to finish?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you should use two client instances. 1 for reading and 1 for writing.

Comment: Going by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipe-operations named pipes can work in duplex so 1 pile should be fine. That being said, I'm not sure if using readasync and writeasync at the same time can cause issues

Comment: There looks like there is a missing `await`s going on here. `Task.WaitAll(outboundTask, inboundTask);` should be `await Task.WhenAll(outboundTask, inboundTask);`. And does `outbox.Take` have an async version like `await outbox.TakeAsync`?

Comment: Changing it to `await Task.WhenAll(outboundTask, inboundTask);` made no difference. Outbox is a `BlockingCollection` which doesn't have an async version of `Take` as far as I can see.
I replaces `await client.ReadAsync` with `await Task.Delay(1000)`  and everything started working properly so I suspect there is some issue with using both `ReadAsync` and `WriteAsync` at the same time although I dont really know another way of doing it

Comment: Try `new NamedPipeClientStream("NamedPipe", ".", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous)` because the default is `PipeOptions.None`. And looking at the source code that is almost certainly the issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/032e8dbd0ca5aee045a41ff78e3c0244d3ec3b51/src/libraries/System.IO.Pipes/src/System/IO/Pipes/PipeStream.cs

Comment: Oh damn, that was it. I had that setup on the server but forgot on the client side. Nice pickup. If you chuck that in an answer I'll be happy to accept it. Thankyou very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default for a pipe is `PipeOptions.None`, but you need `PipeOptions.Asynchronous`

```cs
using (var namedPipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream("NamedPipe", ".",
                              PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
{
```

You should also use `await` whenever possible

```cs
await Task.WhenAll(outboundTask, inboundTask);
```

You appear to be using `BlockingCollection` which unfortunately isn't async. Try to find or create an `async` version of it.